# Have link change a class attribute on page it links to.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

So I'm completely stuck on this one. I'll try and simplify it as best I can. (Also new to the site so hope I post correctly).

Basically I have my main page index file with a menu that links to another page. The other page has all the same contents on the page but automatically starts on "All" contents.

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-inner">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="link">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="posts.html" class="link">All Campaigns</a> </li>
        <li><a href="posts.html" class="link">Latest Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="posts.html" class="link">Most Popular</a></li>
        <li><a href="posts.html" class="link">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Then with the other page, all of its code works perfectly. What I would want to do, for example, is to be able to click "Latest Marketing" on the index page, have it go to that other page like it already does, but to switch the class of "All" to just "sort-link" and change the one under it "Latest" to "sort-link selected". Hope that makes sense. Fairly simple, but wasn't sure how to implement that. Help?

```
<div class="main" id="posts-page">
    <div class="sort-posts">
        <section class="sort-posts-controls clearfix" id="options">
            <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link selected" data-option-value="*">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-latest">Latest</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-popular">Popular</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-music">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-film">Film</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-tv">TV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-sports">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-theater">Theater</a></li>
                <li><a href="#filter" class="sort-link" data-option-value=".is-other">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for a script on one page to alter another page after it's been loaded (barring trickery involving iframes or the like). It is however possible (and easy) for a script on a page that's just been loaded to examine its URL and set the link classes appropriately.

This is assuming that you're actually linking between pages rather than within a page. If you're doing the latter, you can just set a handler for the `hashchange` event and change the classes within it. If you need compatibility with IE7 or below, which don't support `hashchange`, you'll need to set a delegated `click` handler on your sidebar links.